# Yarn add - Private package - 404 Not Found

Tags: yarnpkg

I want to install a private package hosted on an internal Gitlab with Yarn.
So, I configured my `.npmrc` with this informations :

```
@mypackage:registry=https://gitlab.intra/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.intra/api/v4/projects/819/packages/npm/:_authToken=xxxxx
//gitlab.intra/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=xxxxx
always-auth=true
```

When I attempt to install the package with `yarn add @mypackage/lib-node-client`, Yarn give me an error :

```
Trace: 
  Error: https://gitlab.intra/api/v4/projects/725/packages/npm/@mypackage/lib-node-common/-/@mypackage/lib-node-common-21.7.1.tgz: Request failed "404 Not Found"
      at ResponseError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:696:66)
      at new ResponseError (/usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:802:124)
      at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:67062:16)
      at Request.emit (node:events:369:20)
      at Request.module.exports.Request.onRequestResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:141640:10)
      at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:369:20)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:646:27)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:129:17)
      at HTTPParser.execute (<anonymous>)
      at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:512:22)
```

So, Yarn can't find the URL : `https://gitlab.intra/api/v4/projects/725/packages/npm/@mypackage/lib-node-common/-/@mypackage/lib-node-common-21.7.1.tgz`

If I try to get this on my browser, I can download the package...

If anyone can help me please, thank's for all :)

Comment: Okay, so first question, is that part of that internal gitlab really a npm registry or just a place where packages are stored? Do you have the actual link where to download the package from that gitlab?

Answer (score 5):

In your `.npmrc` file, you tell how to connect to GitLab for the project 819. The error is about the project 725. GitLab simply refuse the connexion.

Try with

```
@mypackage:registry=https://gitlab.intra/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.intra/api/v4/projects/725/packages/npm/:_authToken=xxxxx
//gitlab.intra/api/v4/projects/819/packages/npm/:_authToken=xxxxx
//gitlab.intra/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=xxxxx
always-auth=true
```

Comment: That actually worked for me! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 5):

We had a gitlab private package registry, and was constantly getting this error.
`npm i @placeholder/package-name` works fine, but `yarn add @placeholder/package-name` was giving 404 errors.

I tried all possible solutions listed on this thread. At last, there was a section in gitlab on troubleshooting yarn installation [1].
It said,

> try adding this to your .npmrc file (and replace <your_token> with your personal access token or deploy token):

```
//gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:_authToken=<your_token>
```

Our previous `.npmrc` looked like this

```
save-exact=true
unsafe-perm=true
@placeholder:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${PLACEHOLDER_TOKEN}
```

With the above new line addition, it looked like this,

```
save-exact=true
unsafe-perm=true
@placeholder:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${PLACEHOLDER_TOKEN}
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:_authToken=${PLACEHOLDER_TOKEN}
```

With that addition, `yarn add @placeholder/package-name` worked fine.

---

[1] https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/#error-running-yarn-with-the-package-registry-for-npm-registry

Answer (score 0):

This should be the accepted answer. `//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:_authToken=${PLACEHOLDER_TOKEN}` Was the piece I was missing, which supercedes needing to list each project id as in Joel's answer.